# Modal Option on a TD is increasing the line height of the TD in table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a table which has the line height of 1.4 for th and 1.0 for td

But when i add a modal option to one of the TD's, the height of the TD is automatically getting increased to around 2.5, and i am not able to decrease it back to its original size of 1.0.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size of the modal button to btn-xs helped.

Thanks anyways.